# How can I uninstall the local Speech Recognition from Google?

Tags: voice-recognition

My Google Speech Recognition isn't working.  When I use it (in Google Now, Evernote, etc.) it crashes the app.

I'm *guessing* this is because I installed the local SR.
(I did a Factory Reset on the phone (Motorola Razr M) and the problem persists AND the local SR is still installed.

Update: **What I've tried**
I can't find any App (Running or Installed) that seems like Speech Recognition. So I've not removed anything.  The only thing I've seen that looks like it might be what I'm looking for is com.google.android.voicesearch but there's only an option to Stop and Disable it, not uninstall.

Comment: What did you try to uninstall it and why did that not work?

Comment: @Nils see my update above.

Answer (score 1):

You need a rooted device to remove system apps. There are many apps on the market which will do this or you can do it manually via the command line.

[Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD), for example, allows you to "convert" or remove system apps.

**Be careful when removing system apps and do not do anything unless you fully understand what you are doing.**

Answer (score 1):

You might try to stop/disable it. If I do this with a system-app on my Nexus 4 I get a question wether to uninstall all updates. Say yes here, too.

If you want to give it another try, re-enable that app and check for updates and install those.

This way (disabling that sub-component, then re-enabling it) I could get Google Street View to work again within Google Maps.